# create url for file in my file system , web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, url-routing, java-ee-7

[my file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/molav.png)

I tried to show these csv file as url but I failed

how I can get url for file in my file system?

```
 public DownloadFileResponse downloadFile(DownloadFileRequest req) {

      //TODO: create and set ImportMarketResponse object and return the following as response data
      // "EventSet Id: " + req.eventSetId;

        String txt ="EventSet Id: " + req.eventSetId;
        DownloadFileResponse res = new DownloadFileResponse();
        res.setReturnDate(txt);

        return res;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get url for file:

Java 7+

```
Paths.get("path","to","file").toUri().toURL()
```

Older Versions

```
new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```